# Flutter|ListView - hasSize

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

guys!
Need you help.
I have ListView inside AlertDialog:

```
ListView.builder(
           itemExtent: 140,
           shrinkWrap: true,
           scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
           itemCount: tasks.length,
           itemBuilder: (context, index) {
             var tagTwoList = tasks[index].tagTwo;
             return ListTile(
                     visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
                     selected: index == _selectedIndex,
                     selectedTileColor: Colors.indigo.withOpacity(0.7),
                     title: Center(
                         child: tagTwoList),
                     onTap: () {
                       setState(() {
                         _selectedIndex = index;
                       });
                     },
                   );
           }),
```

I tried googling, but the tips that are listed there do not help or do not work correctly. Example: [Get an error `Failed assertion: line 1687 pos 12: 'hasSize'` when render ListTile inside `Row`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61847782/get-an-error-failed-assertion-line-1687-pos-12-hassize-when-render-listtil)
I tried using Expanded, Row, Expanded inside Row.
Now it works with SizedBox, but it looks just awful and when selected, the entire SizedBox is selected:
[image]

If you remove the SizedBox, you get an error:

> RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPhysicalShape#1564b relayoutBoundary=up2
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
> Failed assertion: line 1982 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Comment: What is "when selected, the entire SizedBox is selected"?

Comment: @ZakariaHossain In the screenshot above, "Rasion" is highlighted and you can see that it is highlighted by the size of the SizedBox.

Comment: Can you show the code? you can try wrapping the ListTile inside the SizedBox instead of the other way around, that way only the ListTile itself would be selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a suitable solution, so I corrected the display a bit and now the code looks like this.

```
SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -727,
              child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: tagTwoContainer.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    var tagTwoList = tasks[index].tagTwo;
                    return SizedBox(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, width: 170,
                      child: ListTile(
                        visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
                        selected: index == _selectedIndex,
                        selectedTileColor: Colors.indigo.withOpacity(0.6),
                        title: tagTwoList,
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _selectedIndex = index;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
            ),
```

[image]